# How to put a label to a hierarchical dimension in Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I would like to know if I can set a label to a hierarchical dimension, because If I have 2 dimensions, it will show like below:

[image]

That seems not beauty, so, there is a way to change this with a label or something in qlik sense?

Thanks, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Unlink the Visualization

In the edit panel, click the chain icon and accept to unlink it from the master dimensions. This will allow you to edit the label accordingly.

Of course, this removes it as a master dimension so you it might not be the best if you have numerous sheets using the same chart.

## 2. Add the Label in the Master Visualization

I don't know what the rest of your app looks like, and I've found this to be finicky sometimes so it may not work --play around with it though.

While editing the master table, experiment with using `="Your Label Here"` in the titles of the measures.

---

In my opinion and experience, Qlik Community Forum is more active than Stack Overflow. I highly recommend checking it out for help if you're finding Stack Overflow to be too slow: https://community.qlik.com/